# How to run sbt command and open shell after it's executed

Tags: scala, sbt

How to run sbt command and open shell after it's executed?

Something like:

```
$ sbt package shell
```

so that after 'package' task is executed sbt opens its shell so I can run further commands there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Linux, OSX or another Unix flavour you can write this:

```
sbt package && sbt
```

Here I'm using Unix pipes, to run naked sbt command which opens shell only if previous `sbt package` succeed.

Comment: This would run sbt twice which may take awhile and is exactly what I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: That is not a pipe, it's merely a shorthand for `if sbt package; then sbt; fi`

Comment: @RandallSchulz Yep, I guess there might be some one-word-term for doing this, but sadly I cannot remember/google any.